# Veetle Plugin - Error "Unable to play two streams simultaneously - Mac cannot have two channels open in separate browsers"

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, plugins, streaming, firefox-extensions

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64bits, after a lot of research I finally managed to install the veetle plugin on my firefox browser (I was having trouble because the default I was trying to install was for the 32 bit version). 
Anyway, I finally installed it, it shows up on my firefox plugins, but when I try to open any stream on the website (veetle.com), my browser freezes and I get an error message

```
*"Unable to play two streams simultaneously - Mac cannot have two channels open in* 
*separate browsers"*
```

It stops the broadcast with that message (and yes, I'm only watching that broadcast, not trying to watch it in different browsers / tabs, etc.).

Anyone can give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox, just look in the address bar for the red block symbol, click on it, and for Veetle Player make sure it is set to "allow and remember" instead of "block."